# Updating a properties file injected by Spring to include a last run timestamp

Tags: java, spring, file-io, properties

I have an application which makes used of a properties file loaded by Spring. The Properties instance is then injected into a few classes. The question is some of these properties are updated - for example we have a lastRun timestamp which we want to store here. Maybe there is a better way to go about storing something like this (suggestions welcome), but how can I go about updating the properties file?

```
<util:properties id="props" location="some.properties"/>
```

The `props.store(...)` method requires either a write or an output stream (all of which I'm assuming is unknown as Spring handles this loading)..?

Is there a better approach or should I just be passing in the file path from the Spring context.xml and sending it to various beans and loading/storing the properties file the old fashioned way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PropertiesFactoryBean don't have accessor for location property but  you can get the location property from BeanDefinition.

```
BeanDefinition def = ctx.getBeanFactory().getBeanDefinition("props");
String location = def.getPropertyValues().getPropertyValue("location").getValue();
File file = ctx.getResource(location).getFile();
```

**EDIT**

Include a sample class to do it. You can define the bean in bean the definition file and inject where appropiate.

```
/**
 * Update Spring managed properties
 */
public class SpringPropertyUpdater implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;
    private static final String LOCATION_PROPERTY = "location";
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SpringPropertyUpdater.class);

    /**
     * Update managed properties with new value
     */
    public void  updateProperties(String name, Properties props, String comments) {
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory fb = ctx.getBeanFactory();
        BeanDefinition bf = fb.getBeanDefinition(name);
        String location = (String) bf.getPropertyValues().getPropertyValue(LOCATION_PROPERTY).getValue();
        Resource res = ctx.getResource(location);
        try {
            File file = res.getFile();
            props.store(new FileOutputStream(file), comments);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.ctx = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext;

    }
}
```

Comment: To go about getting `ctx`... is implementing `ApplicationContextAware` and then using `GenericApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext(applicationContext);` the best way to go?

Comment: I dont think this works - I'm not creating a bean, Im using `<util:properties ... />` and I get No bean named 'props' is defined...

Comment: Do you try it?. You are creating a PropertiesFactoryBean.

Comment: 1) Cast the ctx to ConfigurableApplicationContext to get access to getBeanFactory method.